# How can i cancel azure login on powershell?

Tags: linux, azure, powershell

On linux, i installed powershell and Az module. While logging in to Azure account with device authentication (which seems to be the default), if i change my mind or auth doesn't work, how can i cancel the device login?

```bsh
PS /> Connect-AzAccount 
WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXXXX to authenticate.
```

`Ctrl+C` doesn't seem to work. So i need to kill the whole powershell and start over:

- `Ctrl+Z` to push powershell to background
- `kill %1` to kill the suspended process
- `pwsh` to start over with what ever i was doing

I would really like to have a less intrusive and destructive solution...

Comment: You can just close the browser , what do you mean by cancel?

Comment: Since the browser isn't opened by PowerShell (`Connect-AzAccount` provides just the link as shown above, I need to click manually on the link), closing the browser doesn't impact the current command.
With "cancel" i mean, interrupting the login process on the powershell, returning back to command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Disconnect-AzAccount

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/disconnect-azaccount?view=azps-4.3.0

Comment: thanks, but as described PowerShell (`pwsh`) is blocked and doesn't react on `Ctrl+C`; so i don't have the possibility to enter any new commands.

Comment: You would have to wait untill Connect-AzAccount  has completed, and then use the command  Disconnect-AzAccount to cancel the effect of the Connect-AzAccount command. A bit like logging in to a web site and then pressing the logout button afterwards.